# How to make to get a 2 parameter fit using a Non linear model fit in python

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica

Hi I'm very new to python. I was tasked by my Pi to get a 2-parameter fit to an equation I'm using, using a non-linear model fit In python. He did the same but he used mathematica. I'm trying to recreate the same magic but in python. I've attached images [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qe2uZ.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJrJj.png), [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3DD6.png) of what my PI did in Mathematica.

This is what i have so far. Im not asking for you to solve for me. Im asking for a guide

```
  Input = gam0 = 72.8;
  temp = 293.15 ;
  Input= gam[x2_] = gam0 - 0.0187 * temp * 'Natural logarithm[1+628.14*55.556*x2]';
```

Comment: Did you try something yourself as well?  What did you try, what worked, what didn't? Where are you stuck? Do you expect people to translate your code from Mathematica to Python (that's not what this site is made for)? What's your question? Give us something to work with please.

Comment: No of course not. I'm stuck on the first page i tried translating the first few lines but kept getting errors

Comment: Start by removing `Input = `, that's not necessary in Python. Also, semicolons at the end of each line are not part of Python syntax. Taking a logarithm requires importing the math module, you can read more about that [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html) and more specific [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.log)

Comment: So i tried using log in the math module but i keep getting the error TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' or if i remove the quation marks  error name 'math' is not defined

Comment: I'll write a comment to fix these lines of your code but I think a basic online course on python would be more useful since you seem to struggle with python's syntax.

Comment: That would be great. Can you suggest a video i can watch?

Comment: There are thousands of good resources to find if you google something like "Python for beginners". I didn't learn it this way so I can't really point you at one specific but I'm sure you'll find something, try some different channels or websites to find something you enjoy following. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To fix these lines you should write something like this:

```
import math
gam0 = 72.8
temp = 293.15
def gam(x2):
  return gam0 - 0.0187 * temp * math.log(1+628.14*55.556*x2)
```

I'm not familiar with Mathematica's syntax so this might not be 100% equivalent but the logic behind it is the same. 
What did I do?

- remove `input =`, this is not Python syntax.
- remove ; at the end of the lines, this is also no Python syntax.
- I think the last line of your code is a function in Mathematica (not 100%) sure, I rewrote this as a Python function.
- Changed this `'Natural logarithm[1+628.14*55.556*x2]'` to `math.log(1+628.14*55.556*x2)`to make it Python.